# Mock Sql DB connection in Nodejs Unit test cases

Tags: node.js, tedious, sqldb

In My NodeJS Application, Connecting to Sql-DB using tedious, I want to unit test the microservices related to DB.
During the unit test I don't want connect real database.
But I am getting the error

> Error: Unable to connect database: Error:'.connect cannot be called on
> a connection in SentLogin7WithStandardLogin state

Can you recommend any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon) to mock/stub database connection. It works if you use ORM library or native databas library. I usually use **stub** method like this:

```
const sinon = require(‘sinon’);
const chai = require(‘chai’);

it(‘sentence for expected test’, () => {
   let stubDbConnection = sinon.stub(dbLib, ‘connectionMethod’);
   testedFunction();

   chai.expect(stubDbConnection.calledOnce).to.be.true;
});
```

Hope it helps you.
Regards